# BioMart does not return a result

Tags: r, biomart

I am supplying to `BioMart` `81` `ensemblID`s, but getting `80` results where `1` `ensembleID`: `ENSMUSG00000083840` is absent. What does it mean if `BioMart` can not find the gene? Does it mean that it is a non-coding one or that there is just no symbol attached to it? Here is my `BioMart` query:

```
library('biomaRt')
mart <- useDataset("mmusculus_gene_ensembl", useMart("ensembl"))
genes <- rownames(mat)
G_list <- getBM(filters= "ensembl_gene_id", attributes= 
c("ensembl_gene_id","mgi_symbol","description"),values=genes,mart= mart)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever you are wondering about things like this, just look up the identifier on the Ensembl web page. If you [look up](http://www.ensembl.org/Mus_musculus/Gene/Idhistory?g=ENSMUSG00000083840) `ENSMUSG00000083840`, you will see:

> This identifier is not in the current EnsEMBL database

In this case, it doesn't seem to have been replaced by anything and it wasn't a protein coding gene, so it looks like it was simply a wrong annotation which has been removed.